# how to execute a query that is result of another query in sybase

Tags: sybase

I am trying to create a procedure to which I'm passing parameter. Based on this parameter It will select a field from a table which is a Select query(**text datatype**). I want to retrieve the data of this Select query.

SQL query in the table is text data type and Sybase doesn't allow to create text as local variables.

Table1

```
Filter_criteria  Db_query
Incremental      Select a,b,c from table2 where <filter_condition1>
Complete         Select a,b,c from table2 where <filter_condition2>
```

Table2

```
a   b   c
11  12  13
12  13  14
```

If I pass ‘incremental’ to the proc it will return 11,12,13 and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Use execute-immediate. I.e. compose your SQL query dynamically in a varchar variable and then execute it with 'EXECUTE(@your_varchar_variable)'